# Wrap a few asset requires in a javascript closure

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I've got a manifest file `partials.js` which contains this:

```
//= require_tree ./partials
```

And then each coffee file in `./partials/` contains this:

```
$ ->
  # Rest of the code
```

Is it possible to have something like this in the manifest:

```
$(function () {
//= require_tree ./partials
});
```

and remove the `$ ->` wrapping in the individual files?

(This doesn't actually work at the moment. The code gets pushed to the bottom, with the required js above.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently ran into the same issue what I ended up doing was this:

taking your manifest example of:

```
$(function () {
  //= require_tree ./partials
});
```

we can turn it in to a manifest that looks like this:

```
//= require ./head
//= require_tree ./partials
//= require ./tail
```

and then we make `head.js`:

```
$(function (){ //need line to end with semicolon to trick preprocessor;
```

and then we make `tail.js`:

```
});
```

The trick is ending the head.js partial with a commented semicolon. Other wise the preprocesser will try to inject a semicolon breaking the script making someothing like this

```
$(function () {
;
  //rest of your code here
});
```

Comment: The downside of this approach is that you can't really use your JS in non-compressed mode anymore. In development, Rails includes your files individually, so your head.js and tail.js come out as seperate files (with errors).

Comment: As a followup to my comment, I solved that issue by making `head.js` an erb template (`head.js.erb`) and using the rails environment to decide whether or not to render the function head and tail.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to create a load_my_asset.js.erb file:

```
function loadMyAsset() {
    <%= Rails.application.assets.find_asset('path/to/asset').source %>
};
```

and in application.js

```
//= require load_my_asset
```

Which works both in development and production